# Checkbox multiple values to controller using ajax.request

Tags: magento-1.8, controllers, ajax

I have multiple checkbox along with message which I am trying to pass it via ajax.request parameters. I am able to get the message properly in my controller but unable to find the proper solution for multiple checkbox values in controller.

Please guide me with an example. Thanks in advance.

---

**Sample Code : front page**

```
<?php

$sql = SELECT customer_group_id, customer_group_code FROM  customer_group;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='0' width='40%'' height='80px'>";  
       echo "<tr valign=middle>"; 
        echo "<td colspan='5'>";
          echo "<input type='checkbox' value='form1' name='checkall' onclick='checkall();'> Select All ";
        echo "</td>"; 
      echo "<tr>"; 

     echo "<form method='post' action='allnotify.phtml' id='form1'> ";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
       echo "<td>";  
        echo "<input id='{$row['customer_group_id']}' type='checkbox' value='{$row['customer_group_id']}' name='customer_group_id[]'> {$row['customer_group_code']}";   
       echo "</td>";  
    }  
       echo "</tr>";  
    echo "</table>";  
?>

<div class="input-field">
 <label for="custom_field">Type your message : </label>
 <input type="text" class="input-text" name="message" id="message" />

<button type="button" onclick="callController()" title="Send" class="button">Send Notification</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--START : notification for customer grouping-->
checked=false;
function checkall()
{
  var aa= document.getElementById('form1');
  if (checked == false)
    {
      checked = true;
    }
  else
    {
      checked = false;
    }
  for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) { aa.elements[i].checked = checked;}
}
<!--END :  -->


function callController(){

var value = document.getElementById('message').value ;

           new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('customtabs/notify/sendmessage') ?>", {
               method: 'Post',
               parameters: {"message":value},
               onComplete: function(transport) {

        alert('function success ');

               }
           });
       };

 function callsample(){
                 alert('Notify now');        
       }
</script>
</div>
```

---

**controller page**

```
public function sendmessageAction(){
  if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
      {
    $msg = $this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getPost('action');
    if(!empty($msg) and !empty($action)) 
           {
             $notificationmsg =  $msg . "#" . $action ;
           }
           elseif(!empty($msg))
           {
             $notificationmsg =  $msg ;
           }
     elseif(!empty($action ))
           {
             $notificationmsg =  "You have a notification" . "#" . $action ;
           }
           else
           {
              $notificationmsg =  "You have a notification" ;
           }                 
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! While others aim to help you - I'd like to steer you a bit. The sample code you've posted is using direct database queries, and it's bypassing Magento's ORM. This is all happening within a template file. This violates best practice. I really would encourage you to attend the Magento Fundamentals course online or in-person to help get some more education and tools so that you learn the correct way to implement. Best of luck on your journey!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="mydata[message]" id="...
<input type="checkbox" name="mydata[checkbox1]" id="...
<input type="checkbox" name="mydata[checkbox2]" id="...
<input type="checkbox" name="mydata[checkbox3]" id="...
```

You can easily get your POST data in your controller by running:

```
$myPostData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('mydata');
```

Keep in mind that only the checkboxes that are ticked will get to POST

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used ajax.request, so in parameters I am able to pass my text data to controller page but how do I pass checkbox as it will have multiple values in Array.

Comment: Try to serialize your data when you pass them to your Ajax request. I am more familiar with jQuery, but I think with Prototype you can do that : `parameters: Form.serialize(form.id),`